# Calculate the number of active vendor in the last 3 months in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, calculated-columns, countif

I am a newcomer to SQL, I want to calculate the number of active vendors in the last 3 months (A vendor is considered to be active if there is at least one transaction with that vendor within a
certain timeframe)
The data getting from access the https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/iowa-department-of-commerce/iowa-liquor-sales?filter=category:analytics&filter=price:free&filter=solution-type:dataset&project=fiery-plate-322918&folder=&organizationId=  dataset.
Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 1):

The table was updated on Jun 4, 2019. So there are no current data available of the last months.

```
vendor_number
FROM `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales` 
where date>date_sub (current_date(),interval 3 month)
GROUP BY 1
```

returns no data.